# What happens when user uses browser actions with Angular 5 / Ionic 3 PWA?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

When we have a native/hybrid mobile app it normally boils down to user actions via mobile app UI that alter the state of the application.

But now when we have a progressive web app (that may not be yet a full screen UI since the user has not yet added it to home screen etc) we inherit a few additional user actions that we have to treat as a source of truth:

- User can alter / enter new URL
- User can go back / forward
- User can hit refresh

So lets assume the context below:

- we have a PWA with a few lazy loading pages: homepage, aboutpage,
  userpage.
- there is no login auth etc for this example
- when user navigates to www.ourprogressivewebapp.com they land on
  homepage: https://ourprogressivewebapp.com/#/home.page
- our PWA's nav stack now has rootPage = homepage

Questions given the above "state":

1. What happens when user hits refresh at this point? is there a difference in the app behavior between when user entered the original url for the first time (www.ourprogressivewebapp.com) and when they hit 'refresh' (where now address field was showing https://ourprogressivewebapp.com/#/home.page)
2. Now if user clicked inside the app's ui "go to about page" which
   lazy loaded and was pushed to the nav stack (user sees:
   https://ourprogressivewebapp.com/#/about.page, rootpage is homepage but we also have about page in the stack now). What happens if user hits refresh now? will the app "skip" loading homepage?
3. Last one, now user clicked userpage and it was also "pushed" into
   the nav stack (https://ourprogressivewebapp.com/#/user.page). What
   happens if this user will start pressing "back" in their browser?
   will that be interpreted as pop() method and those pages will go
   "off stack" or what really happens in this scenario from app's state
   perspective?

I am looking either for direct answers or help to point me at the articles that cover this behavior in detail.

Answer (score 1):

On preconditions, Pressing back and refresh is possible even after adding to home screen. Back can be performed with "Androids back button" or gesture swipe in iOS and some Android. Pull down of the page will refresh the page.  Just the URL can't be edited as the address bar is not visible.

On all routing conditions, this has nothing to do with PWA. it all depends on how Angular Route is implemented and the behavior is same as of non PWA application. We have our Angular app in dev where we don't use PWA mode(default behavior in Angular 6+) and PWA mode in prod build. Routing and refresh is all just the same in both mode and works just how our routing is coded.

Comment: Hey Anand, sorry did not respond on time. So I understand what you are saying and part of it is helpful. Ionic 3 is not using Angular router, instead it uses NavController which uses routes more like breadcrumbs rather than user navigation source of truth. In Ionic 4 this will go away and Ionic will shift over to Angular router. I will try to recreate a test case and post results here to see if this question can be aswerred deeper